# error is being shown for this line $_GET[' win ']

Tags: php, ajax

I'm using ajax calls to call my php file and passing parameters to the file by using these statements..

In my html file:

```
xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlhttp.open("GET","Elo_algorithm.php?win="+i+"&lost="+j,true);
xml.send();
```

In my php file:

```
$win=$_GET['win'];
$lost=$_GET['lost'];
```

and rest of the code.

But when I run this file I get the following error:

> Notice: Undefined index: win in C:\xampp\htdocs\Elo_algorithm.php on line 4
>   Notice: Undefined index: lost in C:\xampp\htdocs\Elo_algorithm.php on line 6

What should I do?

Comment: Are lines 4 and 6 the `$_GET` lines?

Comment: How exactly are you "running the file"? Are you referring to the returned data from the `xmlhttp` object? Or are you calling `Elo_algorithm.php` in your browser? This might seem like a silly question, but it does happen ;)

Comment: i'm calling the Elo_algorithm.php from my html file.by using XmlHttpRequest object.so its the javascript that shoudl be running the file not my browser or anthing

Comment: @AkshayTakkar: Are you executing these files from a web server?  While you can execute the html file locally from your PC, the php file has to be executed in the context of a web server.  So Kolink's question remains: how exactly are you "running" these files?

Answer (score 5):

Yo have created XMLHttpRequest with

```
 xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
```

but then you have

```
xml.send();
```

instead of

```
xmlhttp.send();
```

Comment: Just wondering if that was the error... How could he be getting anything back from the request?  The xml var might be a typo in the code sample. Either way the issue is the params are null and thus undefined in the $_GET superglobal.

Comment: Well, it's true that you are sending anything in send() method (he could write send(null)) when you use GET with AJAX (unlike POST). Not sure if AJAX GET request works without send method (I haven't tried it), but guess no (though I am not sure). And I can't see any other mistake in his example.

Comment: that code xmlhttp is actually xmlhttp.send() in my file.i just wrote it xmlhttp here by mistake and i'm sending the parameters by xmlhttp.open("GET","Elo_algorithm.php?win="+i+"&lost="+j,true);so how can $_GET('win') variable be undefined

Comment: What are the values of "i" and "j"??  Replace them with strings. If that doesn't work then the use of XmlHttpRequest is wrong. Because that object doesn't behave the same on all browsers I'd recommend using jQuery or another library with a common wrapper around it.

Comment: @AkshayTakkar: as FilmJ asked, are you sure that i and j have values at that point? If not, it would explain why the php script's $_GET array doesn't have any values. Construct the URL first, and display its value to be sure: 

  theUrl = "Elo_algorithm.php?win=" + i + "&lost=" + j; 
  alert("The URL is: " + theUrl); 
  xmlhttp.open("GET", theUrl, true);

Comment: @Alan:this is my code in the html file 
var req=new String();
var xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest;
req="Elo_algorithm.php?win="+i+"&lost="+j;
alert("the url is:"+req);
xmlhttp.open("GET",req,true);
xmlhttp.send();
i even pasted a similar code from w3schools.com and it shows the same problem.

Comment: @FilmJ:my html code and php code are in seperate files.so when i execute the php script in the browser it shows the undefined _$get error which is quite obvious because the script doesn't know that there will be an xmlhttp object in the html file to give it values for $_get variable.so the question is how can i tell the php script that the values for $_get will be provided by xmlhttp object from another file i.e the html file.

Comment: @AkshayTakkar: what did the alert message show?  Did the "win" and "lost" parameters have values in the URL that was displayed?

Comment: @Alan:yes they did.i think the problem is the urls dont know where to go.that maybe a reason its showing undefined error

Answer (score 0):

That's a PHP notice. It means you are accessing an index of an array that doesn't exist. You can turn off notices with the error_reporting setting in php.ini.

Hope that helps.

UPDATE: After the question was revised and code samples more clearly deliniated it was clear that the issue is you weren't actually passing any params.

Comment: A Notice is not a Warning. It's non-blocking, typically means you are accessing a variable that wasn't yet initialized, which is not a requirement in PHP.  In this case probably there is no variable being sent.

Answer (score -1):

I think this error is because of the get variable is not defined yet. Be sure you are using GET or POST correctly.